# How many distinct 5-digit sequences are there, if sequences which are reverse orderings of each other are considered the same?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Reverse order as in 12345 = 54321 ,etc

I understand that the total possibilities of a 5 digit code is $10^5$, so the total number of sets is 100,000. I also know that the answer should be the total number of possibilities divided by the number of equivalence classes. How can I find how many equivalence classes there are?

Comment: @HVxvejjw Do you mind explaining how you reached that number?

Comment: I see no requirement to avoid leading zeros: these are "sequences", not "numbers".

Comment: "five digit numbers "  Who said anything about five digit numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $10^5$ total sequences.

$10*10*10*1*1 = 10^3$ are their own reversals.

$10^5 - 10^3$ are not their own reversal.  So there are are $\frac {10^5-10^3}2$ forward/backward non-self reversing equivalences.

And $10^3$ self-reversing equivalences.

Or $\frac {10^5-10^3}2 + 10^3= \frac{10^5+10^3}2 = 50500$ sequences.

Comment: I understand your reasoning but it still is a little confusing that the 1000 is added back into the total count. Why were they not accounted for in the total count of $10^5$ in the first place?

Comment: Because we divided that number in two under the assumption that for every $abcde$ there was a $edcba$.  If we included $abcba$ and *still* divided in two we'd end up with too few.  So there are $5^5$ $xxxxx$ total.  $5^3$ of them are $abcba$ And $5^5-5^3$ of then are *NOT* $abcba$ so there are $\frac {5^5-5^3}2$ ($abcde/\ne /edcba$) pairs and $5^3$ ($abcba/=/abcba$) singletons.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: count how many $5$-digit sequences are their own reverses.  The rest pair up...

Comment: $10^3$ are their own reverses since 10 x 10 x 10 x 1 x 1? Which makes 1000, so 100,000 / 1000 = 100 should be the answer? But that seems super low, would it be 100,000 - 1000 instead so 99,000 distinct sequences?

Comment: Why are you dividing?

Comment: "would it be 100,000 - 1000 instead so 99,000 distinct sequences".  Now divide that in half (reverse and forward are the same) and add 1000 (you need to count the ones that are self-reversing as well)